# Selecting paths using lasso tool in illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs6

I am trying to seperate a group of paths and am using the lasso tool in illustrator to click and drag around the paths I want to select. Is there a different way to do this? I am finding it difficult to control as I have to click and hold down until I am finished. Here is what I am trying to seperate below. As you can see there are two bananas that sit close so it is a bit tricky trying to seperate them using the lasso tool.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the Lasso tool.. use the **Direct Selection tool** (the white arrow) to click-drag across parts you want, using Shift to add to the selection when needed.

This particular art merely takes **one drag** with the **Direct Selection tool**, holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key. You don't need to drag to *surround* everything. Simply drag so the visible preview selection box *touches* a path or shape and it becomes part of the selection.

[image]

If the artwork is more complex and you can't merely drag once, you can switch to **outline mode** and and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to drag several times. Then switch back to Preview Mode when you've got the selection...

[image]

<sub>(Note: I'm holding down the `Option/Alt` and `Shift` keys as I drag with the Direct Selection tool.)</sub>

---

The Lasso tool, for the most part, is pointless and another Adobe addition that isn't really any more helpful and exists merely so users *feel* things are more familiar. No one *needs* the Lasso Tool -- some may prefer to use it, but it does *not* contain *any* unique features. At most, in some use cases, it may save a couple/few click-drags, that's all.